# sorting with a condition Grade Letters

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort grade letters where B+ must be before B etc.

```
import random
grades = ['A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'F']
random.shuffle(grades)
print(grades)

['C', 'B', 'F', 'B+', 'D+', 'A', 'A-', 'C-', 'C+', 'B-', 'D']
```

Using `sorted` function brings B before B+, etc.
I used the `key` with sorted function but I am not aware how exactly to use it!

```
sorted(grades, key=lambda x: x.endswith('+'))
```

Any help is appreciated.

I searched a lot for a similar question without success!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use the `int` value from `bool`,

   - if there is `+` it'll be `-1`
   - if there is `-` it'll be `1`
   - if none of, it'll be 0

   ```
   grades.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], - x.endswith('+') + x.endswith('-')))
   ```
2. Using a **mapping dict** to convert sign to a number to be sorted :

   ```
   lettermap = {'-': 2, '': 1, '+': 0}
   grades.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], lettermap[x[1:]])) # tuple to have multiple criterias
   print(grades) # ['A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'F']
   ```

   - Same with inline dict

     ```
     grades.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], {'-': 2, '': 1, '+': 0}[x[1:]]))
     grades.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], {'-': 2, '+': 0}.get(x[1:], 1)))
     ```

Answer (score 2):

The key function maps the elements to real numbers, the `sort` function will then sort the elements in your list by those values. In order to produce such `keys` for the `sort` function, try mapping the letters to integers e.g. with `ord` and adjust those values to decimals if there is a sign after!

```
def keyfunc(grade):
    value = ord(grade[0]) #every letter gets mapped to a number
    if len(grade)>1:
        if grade[1] == '+': #plus grades rank higher -> subtract a little
            value -= 0.3
        else:
            value += 0.3 #for minus , add a little
    return value
sorted(grades, key=keyfunc)
```

this produces:

```
['A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'F']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dict.get` and supply a default return:

```
sorted(grades, key=lambda g: (g[0], {'-': 2, '+': 0}.get(g[-1], 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could map each of the letter grades directly to a numerical value and sort based on that:

```py
mapping = {'A': 10, 'A-': 9, 'B+': 8, 'B': 7, 'B-': 6, 'C+': 5, 'C': 4, 'C-': 3, 'D+': 2, 'D': 1, 'F': 0}

sorted(grades, key=lambda x: mapping[x.upper()], reverse=True)
# ['A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'F']
```

Comment: The letters can be any other one string small or capital

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced version of @peer's answer. More case handling like 'A+' > 'b-' and grades such as "A++".

```
def grade_valuator(grade):
    postgrade = grade.upper()
    value = 0
    i = 2
    while(len(postgrade) > 0):
        if postgrade[0] == '+':
            value -= .5 ** i
            i += 1
        elif postgrade[0] == '-':
            value += .5 ** i
            i += 1
        elif postgrade[0].isalnum():
            value += ord(postgrade[0])
        postgrade = postgrade[1:]
    return value
```

Code use examples:

```
grades = ['+d', 'b+', 'A', 'A-', 'C-', 'C', 'A+', 'C++', 'b-', 'A++', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'C+', 'C+-', 'F', '--C']


sorted(grades, key=grade_valuator) #Get a new sorted copy of the list
#['A++', 'A+', 'A', 'A-', 'b+', 'B', 'b-', 'C++', 'C+', 'C+-', 'C', 'C-', '--C', '+d', 'D', 'E', 'F']

print(grades)
#['+d', 'b+', 'A', 'A-', 'C-', 'C', 'A+', 'C++', 'b-', 'A++', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'C+', 'C+-', 'F', '--C']

grades.sort(key=grade_valuator) #Sort the list in-place
print(grades)
#['A++', 'A+', 'A', 'A-', 'b+', 'B', 'b-', 'C++', 'C+', 'C+-', 'C', 'C-', '--C', '+d', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```